# How to forward specific file to syslogserver

Tags: logging, rsyslog, forwarding

I have a service application which write its logs at /home/my_app/logs.txt

I'm trying to forward this logs to a centralized syslog server but it seems that logs are not forwarded.

-What I have done so far -

1. I create a new file in /etc/rsyslog./forward.conf

   ```
    action(type="omfile" file="/home/my_app/logs.txt")
    stop
    $ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on    # save messages to disk on shutdown
    $ActionQueueType LinkedList      # run asynchronously
    $ActionResumeRetryCount -1       # infinite retries if host is down
    *.* @@mySyslogServer:514;RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat
   ```
2. Update my logfile and check if the new line passed to syslog server side

   > vi //home/my_app/logs.txt       ##add line and save

New log did not forwarded to syslogserver.

I have checked also relative posts but I saw that log file was accesible (visible) in journalctl but I can't add that service to systemd so I have to find out a way to use the file that its already generated.

Comment: You can't just add a new line to the log file and expect it to be sent to the remote syslog server. For testing, you can use the logger command in the shell, e.g. `logger "Hello to logs.txt"`; which then should be forwarded to the syslog server.

Answer (score 2):

First things first:

You can't just add a new line to the log file and expect it to be sent to the remote syslog server. For testing, you can use the logger command in the shell, e.g. `logger "Hello to logs.txt"` which then should be forwarded to the syslog server.

---

I'm not sure, how it works with the "old" (deprecated) rsyslog syntax. Using the "new" advanced syntax though, log forwarding would look like this:

```
*.* {
    # Local
    action(type="omfile" file="/home/my_app/logs.txt")

    # Syslog over UDP
    action(type="omfwd" target="192.168.1.2" port="514" protocol="udp"
        queue.type="linkedlist" queue.saveOnShutdown="on"queue.resumeRetryCount="-1")
}
```

This will log **all** messages locally to `/home/my_app/logs.txt` and forward all logs to the syslog server on `192.168.1.2`.

---

**NOTE**: You still need to adjust your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file to include all configs files (files in `/etc/rsyslog.d/`), include modules and define a messages template.

*It's not clear from your post if you've done this.*

---

**P.S.** I prefer to use `queue.type="fixedarray"` as it is faster (in most cases).